# Writing a 6-term Exact Sequence

Tags: diagrams, xy-pic

I am trying  to use the `xymatrix` package to write the following exact sequence

```
$\xymatrix{
A \ar[r] & B \ar[r] &C \ar[d] & \\ 
 \ar[u]& D \ar[l]& E \ar[l]& F 
}$
```

When I write `\ar[r]` in the second line everything works perfectly; but when I write `\ar[l]` I get an error for some reason...

Any idea how to fix it so that the two horizontal arrows in the second line go to the left?

Comment: There's something strange in your diagram; I can add `\ar[l]` after `F`, but what I get is: an arrow from `A` to `B`, one from `B` to `C`, one from `C` to `E` (vertical), one from `F` to `E`, one from `E` to `D`; also there are a horizontal arrow from `D` to nothing and a vertical one from nothing to `A`. Is this what you want? Please, try making clear how the diagram should look.

Comment: Well if you replace `\ar[l]` in my code by `\ar[r]` in the second line... you get exactly the diagram I want, which is like a box if you will,  but with the  arrows in the second row reversed !

Comment: I'm not sure I'm making myself very clear, but I have no idea how to get the diagram here !

Comment: So you want `A → B → C` in the upper row, `D ← E ← F` in the lower row, with vertical arrows from `C` to `F` and from `D` to `A`?

Comment: That's EXACTLY what I want!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}
$\xymatrix{ A \ar[r] & B \ar[r] &C \ar[d] & \\
 D \ar[u]& E \ar[l]& F \ar[l] }$
\end{document}
```

an arrow needs to appear at the node from which it starts.
the `D` in the second line should be before the first `&`, and
proceed from there.

here's what the output looks like:

[image: output of example code]

---

Here's the same diagram with `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
A \ar{r} & B \ar{r} & C \ar{d} \\
D \ar{u} & E \ar{l} & F \ar{l}
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Diagram with tikz-cd]

Comment: `\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}`, please. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg -- you're right, of course.  fixed.

Comment: I did as you said, and I still get arrows to the right !

Comment: @Selena -- i've added the image from the test file.  if you're getting something else, there must be something you're not telling us.

Comment: @barbarabeeton My apologies, it worked! I must've done something wrong at first... Thank you!